# Trying to get the selection of a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the selection from the drop-down list and save it into the database as its corresponding primary key.

When the user makes a selection, I am unable to use that selection.  I think I am not collecting the correct information in my controller.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type.TypeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Types", ViewBag.Types as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type.TypeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateCommunicationViewModel commmodel){
...

   var typeIDquery = db.Types.Where(g => g.TypeName == commmodel.Type.TypeName).Select(g => g.TypeID);
   typeID = typeIDquery.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().Trim().ToString();
```

Comment: Where does this code fail exactly? What does "unable to use that selection" mean?

Comment: In the controller, the typeIDquery is always null.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what `commodel.Type.TypeName` holds?

Comment: Good advice :) I just checked, and it holds null, even when a selection has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you posted your complete code of your view but I think you are missing the HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Get)) {....}
```

And in your Create method your parameter name has to match the name of dropdown list you are trying to catch:

```
public ActionResult Create(string Types){....}
```

The 'Types' parameter at your action method should be the selected value from the dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you! Passing in string Types as a parameter has solved everything.